# How to allow for people to purchase gifts for others

Tags: contributions, contribution-page

We are using Civi in wordpress.

We are going to use Civi to host an 'adopt an object' scheme for our Museum. We anticipate that we will get a lot of people buying them as 'gifts' and will need the information of both purchaser and recipient. However, we need to make a distinction between them so we don't send the 'thank you' immediately to the recipient, that we know where the data came from and can manage that at our end.

Is there a way to:

1. Collect individual data for 2 'types' of people and make that distinct in the form.
2. Delay a 'thank you' email to the recipient.

Answer (score 2):

We actually solved for a "gift certificate" type need by utilizing the "Honoree" section on the contribution page. Doing so creates a soft credit type contribution on the honoree's contact record so that way you know who purchased it and who's the beneficiary. After that, it's pretty manual, but you can use CiviRules to assign an activity or send an email to someone on staff who can handle the next steps. After doing this manually for a while (as described above), we have now written requirements, and are planning to commission someone to write a CiviCRM extension for us to automate the process a bit.

The receipt goes to the purchaser (not the giftee/honoree), and in it, we include a link to a nice gift certificate they can print, and write in the gift amount, recipient's name, etc. Hoping to automate this part, too.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, Civi on Wordpress is in the midst of a transition in how to make web forms. Up until now, we have used Caldera Forms with the [CF-Civicrm](https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm) plugin. The combination is very powerful and allows you to capture data on multiple contacts on a single form, with addresses, phone #s, and emails for each person, with groups, tags and relationships. It sounds like it would do what you want here.

The delayed email would require a little extra thought, for example it might be triggered by a scheduled job in Civi.

But the Caldera company was bought out, and they are transitioning users to Ninja Forms by 12/31/2021. There is a Civicrm addon in development, for details see [this post](https://calderaforms.com/2021/09/conversion-tool-1-0-live-more-transition-updates/), toward the bottom of the page. I'm hopeful that it will allow us to do the same things we do now, but time will tell.

So if you don't need this immediately you may want to start learning Ninja Forms, starting laying out your forms, and add the Civi addon when it becomes available later.

Answer (score 0):

CiviRules allows for delays on sending emails after various triggers